# Artifactory has artifactory.sh vs artifactorymanage.sh. Can i use artifactory.sh for production?

Tags: artifactory

Initially we will have only 5 projects only for next 6 months.
Starting artifactorymanage.sh is challenging

so initially can i use artifactory.sh and configure things and later move to artifactorymanage.sh?

Comment: This is an off-topic question that doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Comment: @ParkingMaster: All programming artifacts are getting stored here only. All dependencies are picked from here only and also section is there on stackoverflow dedicated to artifactory. So i thought it can be asked.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer which is related which means artifactorymanage.sh is for database externally used where internally it uses Derby:

Artifactory does come with a built-in embedded Derby database that is suitable for small-scale installations, testing, or evaluations. This embedded database allows users to quickly set up and run Artifactory without the need for an external database management system.

While the embedded Derby database can be convenient for getting started with Artifactory, it's important to keep in mind that it might not be the best choice for larger or production-scale deployments. Derby's embedded nature and design can lead to limitations in terms of scalability, performance, and reliability compared to dedicated database systems like MySQL, PostgreSQL, or others.

For small projects, evaluation purposes, or temporary setups, the embedded Derby database can serve its purpose well. However, if you plan to use Artifactory in a production environment with significant artifact storage, high user loads, and the need for advanced database management features, it's generally recommended to migrate to an external database system for better performance and scalability.

As always, it's a good practice to consult the official Artifactory documentation and guidelines for the most accurate and up-to-date information on database options and best practices.